# A hard to understand sentence

Tags: meaning

## Problem

I am currently reading computer science literature in data privacy. However, I encountered the following sentence that seems confusing to me

> In other words, we ask for a refinement of Dalenius's goal: that nothing about an individual should be learnable from a dataset that cannot be learned from the *same dataset but with that individual's data removed*.

[*The Ethical Algorithm: The Science of Socially Aware Algorithm Design*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QmmtDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=%22That+nothing+about+an+individual+should+be+learnable+from+a+dataset+that+cannot+be+learned+from+the+same+dataset+but+with+that+individual%27s+data+removed.%22&source=bl&ots=f4P4Jxhndv&sig=ACfU3U2-xE-EN3hnLxavydEjiCyxrlzbCg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiljK6L1pzmAhVPj54KHUkMCooQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22That%20nothing%20about%20an%20individual%20should%20be%20learnable%20from%20a%20dataset%20that%20cannot%20be%20learned%20from%20the%20same%20dataset%20but%20with%20that%20individual's%20data%20removed.%22&f=false)

I understand "that nothing ... from a **dataset**", but not sure about the meaning of modifier of **dataset**. From the context of the text, it seems that the sentence should mean "with and without individual's data makes no difference".

However, I think it is still necessary to fully understand this sentence because it uncovers some design principle of data privacy.

Could someone help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: So I should still be able to watch the cable channel that they dropped from the line-up because I still have all the other channels??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> nothing about an individual should be learnable from a dataset [A] that cannot be learned from [another dataset B, which is incidentally] the same dataset but with that individual's data removed.

We should derive the same information about individual X from both datasets:

- The original dataset that contains data about X.
- The modified dataset that *does not* contain data about X.

Comment: Nice. To address OP's sub-question about the modifer: "that cannot be learned from..." modifies "nothing".